How can one voltage value have multiple SOC? (Jackery Blog Graph)

https://www.jackery.com/blogs/knowledge/lithium-ion-battery-voltage-chart
This is a typical voltage discharge curve for a li-ion battery. I am wondering how one voltage value can translate to multiple SOC? Specifically, for a voltage of ~3.5V this curve predicts the battery to be ~80%, ~60%, and ~20% SOC.
For such a wide range of values it makes me question the usefulness of such a curve. How can you possibly know which SOC it is at a voltage of 3.5V?
I am currently trying to do regression on this curve and invert the function so I can predict the SOC by inputting any voltage value. I'm having trouble doing this though because the function is not invertible as the signs of the derivative is very clearly changing between 80-20%.
I am seeking some input on if there is something wrong with the graph and if there might be a way of correcting for any errors in the curve. Thanks

I've seen this figure before; I doubt the veracity of the website generally, as it's a highly-SEO'd landing page. The overly soft curve looks like a victim of polynomial or spline smoothing.

I think the 10000USD gift card ad illustrates the reliability of the data on the website.

"This is a typical voltage discharge curve for a li-ion battery" ... are you sure about that?

a voltage snapshot is a poor indicator of SoC; i've had much better luck using the delta of two snapshots and integrating WH to arrive at an estimate.

It's possible that that graph was perturbed by the battery getting warmer as the discharge progressed.

The typical lithium-ion SoC curve is generally monotonic, unlike the plot shown to you. However, there is a substantial region that is nearly flat, with nearly unchanging voltage as the SoC varies in that range.
This means that your question can be answered in two ways:

First, that curve looks unusual and inconsistent with reality. It's possible that sparse data points were inappropriately smoothed by Excel or similar, which has no idea that the curve must be monotonic and uses a totally inappropriate smoothing algorithm. (such smoothing is nice for visual appeal, but makes it hard to faithfully represent data in many cases, especially when the individual points are gone)
My personal view is that if a website/resource publishes a curve like that without noticing red flags about their graph being meaningless and misleading, I wouldn't trust their other claims, nor the products they're selling.

Second, using voltage and inverting the SoC is likely to provide poor estimation over a large portion of the charge curve in the middle. The voltage variation from temperature, etc will cause significant error. Other techniques, such as integrating current, may need to be used.


There are tons of better examples of charge curves out there - this published article includes a nice example of a curve for a related chemistry, reproduced below:


Hi is there any better examples for specifically li-ion chemistry? I am also wondering if there is any monotonic feature in excel that could give a better graph as they provide the data points in the article, and I could do the regression myself. Thank you so much for your detailed response.

@risa There are a lot of charge curves out there = simply searching "lithium ion state of charge curve" gives a lot of good results. Second, trying to use an excel feature for monotonicity is just putting a band-aid on bad data. I haven't seen the article in question so I cannot see the data points, but my sense is that sensing just voltage is inherently troublesome for lithium chemistries, and no amount of regression or data wrangling is going to change that fundamental issue

I see.. thank you

It isn't like this curve was designed to tell us how full the battery is, it is instead a curve that naturally occurs when battery discharges.
So its "usefulness" that you are questioning is what it is.  There's no way to change it and make it more useful.
What you posted is very theoretical. Usually the characteristic is something like this.
The voltage around 20-70% na needs to be measured relatively precisely to get accurate % of the chatge.


For such a wide range of values it makes me question the usefulness of such a curve. How can you possibly know which SOC it is at a voltage of 3.5V?

Just look at the tables that website provides, I copied one below. The voltage is strictly decreasing as the charge capacity is decreasing. It happens for 3.4V cells and also for 12V, 24V and 48V. This is as expected. The plot they have provided there has some flaws and is clearly not based on the numbers they provided.



Charge Capacity (%)
1 Cell
12 Volt
24 Volt
48 Volt




100
3.40
13.6
27.2
54.4


90
3.35
13.4
26.8
53.6


80
3.32
13.3
26.6
53.1


70
3.30
13.2
26.4
52.8


60
3.27
13.1
26.1
52.6


50
3.26
13.0
26.0
52.5


40
3.25
13.0
26.0
52.4


30
3.22
12.9
25.8
52.0


20
3.20
12.8
25.6
51.6


10
3.00
12.0
24.0
48.0


0
2.50
10.0
20.0
40.0



